# QML GridLayout does not obey my specified cell arrangements

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

In this code, some items are invisible at first. I want them to be visible on the click of a button **at the place where they have been placed by me**.

In order to leave space for them, I have placed the other item where it will be shown when hidden options will be visible.

My problem is that `GridLayout` does not obey the following cell positions set in code when other items are invisible.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 500; width: 500

    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout

        property bool secondScreenOptionsVisible: false

        property int hmmiButtonRow: 0
        property int hmmiButtonCol: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: hmmi; visible: gridLayout.secondScreenOptionsVisible
            Layout.row: gridLayout.hmmiButtonRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.hmmiButtonCol;
            height: 50; width: 50; color: "pink";
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            Text { text: "HMMI"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        property int optionsButtonRow: 1
        property int optionsButtonCol: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: optionsButton; visible: gridLayout.secondScreenOptionsVisible
            Layout.row: gridLayout.optionsButtonRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.optionsButtonCol;
            height: 50; width: 50; color: "red"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            Text { text: "Options..."; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        property int flipperControlRow: 3
        property int flipperControlCol: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: flipperControl;
            Layout.row :gridLayout.flipperControlRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.flipperControlCol;
            height: 200; width: 50;
            color: "brown";
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            Text { text: "Flipper"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

When all the items are visible:

[image]

When other two items are hidden, the `GridLayout` does not obey the rules.

[image]

**I want `GridLayout` to obey the cell positions set by me, irrespective of whether other items are visible or not.**

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says for `GridLayout` that:

> [...] It is similar to the widget-based QGridLayout. All **visible** children of the GridLayout element will belong to the layout. [...].

So what you are seeing is a direct consequence of the implementation approach followed by developers. Indeed a change in visibility triggers `Item`s repositioning, as can be seen in [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/layouts/qquicklinearlayout.cpp?h=5.5#n516) code path.

Instead of considering `visible` property you can use `opacity` property: the non-opaque `Item`s are taken in account by the layout, resulting in the expected visible behaviour. See for instance this simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400; width: 400

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: gridLayout
        rows: 3
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            id: rep
            model: 9

            Rectangle {
                color: "black"
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                Layout.preferredHeight:  100
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                opacity: index === rep.count - 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mind that non-opaque `Item`s are still rendered, differently from invisible ones, with a varying degree of impact over performances, depending on your actual use case.

Comment: The link is broken. I'm guessing it was around 5.5 that it was referring to, but could you please edit it to correct the link? Maybe [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/layouts/qquicklinearlayout.cpp?h=5.5#n516) is where it was pointing?

Comment: @Mitch thanks for the pointer. I've updated the link with the new url.